# Facebook graph api automatic graph api access token generator

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, automation, token

this i was trying and have written this to my actual code but not able to retrive any token please correct this i want to able to get a acess token generator with a frsh code to this as Trying to generate a graph api acess token by itself without explicitely logging into the facebook developer portal but showing error i want a corrected code for the same

```
import requests

def refresh_access_token(old_token):
    app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID'
    app_secret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET'
    refresh_token = 'YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN'

    url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/oauth/access_token'
    params = {
        'grant_type': 'fb_exchange_token',
        'client_id': app_id,
        'client_secret': app_secret,
        'fb_exchange_token': old_token
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    data = response.json()

    new_token = data.get('access_token')
    return new_token

# Replace 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' with your current access token
old_token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
new_token = refresh_access_token(old_token)

print(f"Old Token: {old_token}")
print(f"New Token: {new_token}")
```

output--

```
Old Token: EAAKReLBB3TsBOxdukWb14iW1PrRtwbLxMgGl5l2eBhw3ZBXPmJV7aIadj1ZBkaZCHnsIY6pNgrSQPZABTzvviK4sEvA3vc8U5fgkrEXiZBVkhvWtt3Y74xDZCxHPSwmMbtZBlNhdISrNsiZAKSoPQvj94zwpcZD
New Token: None
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.